# Showing activity indicator in android

Tags: android

I am new to android.I need to show an activity indicator while synchronizing.On clicking a button,i am redirecting to a new activity.In this new activity i am synchronizing.I need to show an activity indicator on button click till it is synchronized.

Comment: What is 'activity indicator'? A progress bar?

Comment: yes i mean the progressbar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Synchronizing is effectively a network task  And you have to do this on Background ( [Async Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)) So you can call an AsyncTask in your new Activity

```
private class SyncOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

      ProgressDialog progressDialog;

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

          // Synchronize code here

             return null;
      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {   
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }            
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
                     if (progressDialog == null) {
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Synchronizing, please wait...");
                    progressDialog.show();
                    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                }   
      }


}
```

Now in `OnCreate()` of new Activity

```
SyncOperation syncTask=new SyncOperation();
syncTask.execute();
```

It will show a loader like

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But for my new class i am already extending activity class,then how can i extend  AsyncTask .

Comment: Just make it as an inner class of your activity class